# Can a temple be built in place of a Masjid?

Tags: sharia, fiqh, non-muslim, masjid, non-muslim-countries

As Salaam Alikum,

In a case in India year 1992, some Hindus claim that a Masjid (mosque) Babri, was built over the birth place of their lord Ram. So they demolished the Masjid, which gave rise to riots between Hindus and Muslims, and the matter remains unsolved for years.

Now, some Hindus say that leave the birth place of Ram, give the place to Hindus, and take same area space somewhere else in India.

So, they want to build a Temple in place of the present Babri Masjid, demolish the present one and are telling Muslims to built a new Babri Masjid somewhere else.

Is this exchange of worship places allowed in Islam?

Comment: http://islamqa.info/en/152263

Comment: In 1949 Hindu activists associated with the Hindu Mahasabha placed idols of Ram inside the mosque, after which the Indian government locked the building to avoid further disputes. Court cases were filed by both Hindus and Muslims asking for access. On 6 December 1992, a large group of Hindu terrorists belonging to the Vishva Hindu Parishad and allied parties demolished the mosque, triggering riots all over India. In 2019, under the current right wing Hindu govt, the Supreme Court has stated it was illegal to place idol & demolish a masjid but allowed Hindus to build their temple there now :-/

Answer (score 1):

As it is famous for Muslims, Masjid (mosque) is a place in which Muslims prayer there for Allah. Then there mustn't be another thing such as the temple of their ram (of Hindus). Thus as much as you can, it is your duty to prevent doing it. Since it would be offensive if this symbol of Shirk be in the mosque of Allah.